# Is there a way to get NFS to refresh its reverse lookup without restarting it?

Tags: linux, nfs, mdns, avahi, reverse-dns

NFS server for some reason doesn't seem to acknowledge that avahi/mdns will resolve an ip address unless NFS is restarted after avahi is already running.

I have my exports specified by hostname (with .local appended), and the NFS client keeps getting denied access by the server because the NFS server claims not to be able to do a reverse lookup unless I restart the server after having started avahi.

The server errors are of the form:

```
syslog:Feb 24 12:40:11 rdk2-laptop mountd[1623]: refused mount request from 169.254.5.152 for /opt/ros/electric (/opt/ros/electric): unmatched host
```

Is there a way around this?

Comment: You mean the NFS server or client? It sounds like you're asking about an NFS client that won't connect to a server `avahi` unless the server is running. But that would be a forward DNS lookup, not a reverse one.

Comment: Sorry I should have specified: The server. I'll update with more specifics.